# NetBeans - Programmatically Remove NotificationDisplayer Notifications

Tags: netbeans

The NetBeans API provides the org.openide.awt.NotificationDisplayer class to create and show clickable notifications in the main status line. For example,

```
NotificationDisplayer.notify(title, icon, detailsText, detailsAction);
```

The user can dismiss a notification by clicking on the X; however, I would like to programmatically clear the notifications. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I end up with was to maintain a reference to the Notification object returned by the NotificationDisplayer.notify() method. The object provides a clear() method to force removal from the status line.

Comment: Thanks for sharing - didn't spot that it returns the Notification